# How do I add thousand separators to a number in array with the response coming from sever

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I check the array and add thousand separators to the number which is in thousands?

This is my JSON:

```
{
"message": "Successfully  data has been fetched.",
"success": true,
"data": {
    "dataHeaders": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3,
        "4",
        "5",
        "6"
    ],
    "dataArray": {
        "A": [
            "A",
            "45567",
            "545",
            "5",
            "10",
            "45",
            "24"
        ],
        "B": [
            "B",
            "40",
            "75465",
            "6",
            "6",
            "30",
            "25"
        ],
        "C": [
            "C",
            "30",
            "10",
            "3",
            "46565",
            "40",
            "65"
        ],
        "D": [
            "D",
            "307676",
            "10",
            "3",
            "4",
            "40",
            "65"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

In the above JSON I need to add the separators which is inside the arrays `dataArray` using jQuery or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, as always, Regular Expressions:

```
// add a comma every 3 digits, as a thousand separator
// only works with integer numbers
function number_format(n) {
    return String(n).replace(/\d(?=(?:\d\d\d)+$)/g, '$&,')
}
```

Comment: But i also need to loop through the json and check for the number and then append the seperator wen needed. As i am new to json and javasc rioting i am little lost here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use .toLocaleString in javascript:

Something like:

```
function number_format(n) {
  var int_language = "en-EN";
  return parseFloat(n).toLocaleString(int_language);
}
```

Comment: But i also need to loop through the json and check for the number and then append the seperator wen needed. As i am new to json and javasc rioting i am little lost here

Comment: okay do you know that the structure is always the same in the json or is it variable as well? At first I would read this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ to parse JSON and get the arrays inside. And check if it's a number or not.

Comment: The structure remains the same always. Its always going to be a number.